# How to teach maven CAS Authentification

Tags: maven, cas

I'd like to add CAS (with HTML login form) support to maven

I'm currently prototyping my thought :

1. I've setup a brand new nexus install
2. Placed it behind a CAS enabled Apache
3. Hook up the apache with my target CAS server
4. Test the whole thing from a browser ==> OK
5. Test maven artifact resolution ==> KO (as expected)

The worst thing is that maven handle the response page as the jar ...

My first try was to build an [Alternative Wagon Providers](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-wagon-providers.html) but I can't make it work ...
Alternative provider is deployed but my config is ignored at runtime :

```
-Dmaven.wagon.provider.http=extendedHttp
```

nor

```
<wagonProvider>http-extendedHttp</wagonProvider>
```

Inside the new provider's jar :

```
<component-set>
    <components>
      <component>
        <role>org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon</role>
        <role-hint>http-extendedHttp</role-hint>
        <implementation>org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.extended.ExtHttpWagon</implementation>
        <instantiation-strategy>per-lookup</instantiation-strategy>
      </component>
      <component>
        <role>org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon</role>
        <role-hint>https-extendedHttp</role-hint>
        <implementation>org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.extended.ExtHttpWagon</implementation>
        <instantiation-strategy>per-lookup</instantiation-strategy>
      </component>
    </components>
</component-set>
```

What did I do wrong ??